# Check if one of the elements of array is within other array

Tags: php

I want to check to see if a voucher is valid for an event. 
The voucher can be valid on certain days (mo-su) which is stored in an array:

```
$validOn = [1,3,4]; // Monday, Thursday
```

An event can be happening on 1 or more days:

```
$event = [2,6]; // Tuesday, Saturday (unique)
```

How can I check if the voucher is valid for the given event?

```
valid([2,6], $validOn); // false
valid([1,6], $validOn); // true
valid([1,4], $validOn); // true
valid([3], $validOn);   // true
etc etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$result = array_intersect($validOn, $event);
if(count($result) > 0) {
  //we have a match
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php for more information as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_intersect`

```
function valid($a, $b) {
   return  count(array_intersect($a, $b)) > 0;
}
```